# Yeast comparison source

Tags: yeast

Is there a good source that compares the commercially available yeast strains from the most common sources like White Labs and Wyeast?

I am thinking of something with homebrewing experience built into them: the differences of using WLP002 and WLP007 for, say, an English bitter, or WLP013 or WLP004 for a dry stout. What differences in character they make when using such and such recipe.

Of course, I would also like standard specs like average attenuation and temperature ranges to whether they are fruity, phenolic, dry, etc, but these are not so hard to obtain on your own.

Answer (score 4):

The closest thing I know of is http://tinyurl.com/yeastbot

Answer (score 1):

I'm an unemployed developer, and I saw this question the other day - give this a try!

http://yeastbot-on-rails.herokuapp.com/

It needs to be improved as the search function is a bit iffy (for example, partial matches don't work at the moment: searching for `Oktoberfest` only returns some of the yeasts that match because some are written as `Oktoberfest/Märzen`.  I will speak with the person who maintains the Yeastbot DB and figure out a way to make things work smoother.  Also the design will improve but...anyway, hope it helps!  If there's some other feature you'd like to see or a way to make it work better, please let me know :)

**edit**:

since there are probably a lot of stackoverflow users here, you can find the git repository [here](https://github.com/daxdefranco/YeastBot-on-Rails) should you want to contribute!

Comment: Very nice initiative! Where do you load the data from? Yeastbot?

Comment: yeah, from Yeastbot :) and thanks!  actually I'm looking for work at the moment, so any extra project I can show helps :p